# Update Properties from Base ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms app and I have an instance of the ViewModel data of my current page deserialised to its correct type in my Base ViewModel. My Base ViewModel also implements INotifiyPropertyChangedInterface. The view model data that has been serialized contains the properties with the correct data.

I was expecting it to bind automatically since the INotifiyPropertyChangedInterface is implemented. But nothing happens. Do I need to do anything further? If you need any further information to help me, please ask. There was not much code that I could paste in except the deserializing the json.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look something like this:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string nameValue = string.Empty;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return nameValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != nameValue)
            {
                nameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    // This method should be called by the Set accessor of each property.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how it implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and calls the right method whenever a value is set. Failing to do so, will cause the UI not to be updated.

Now to bind your value, do this in XAML, somewhere on your page: `<Label Text="{Binding Name}" />`. Lastly, you have to set the `BindingContext` property of your page, like this:

```
public MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Bert";

        BindingContext = person;

        person.Name = "Ernie";
    }
}
```

To take out the boilerplate code and call the `PropertyChanged` method on each property, have a look at the [PropertyChanged.Fody plugin](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).

Comment: I have done pretty much all of this, except that i am using Fody to weave the property changes.